# Is it possible to access current object while doing list/dict comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to think of a one-liner to achieve the following (summing all the values of a key):

```
>>> data = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 4), ('c', 9), ('b', 1), ('d', 3)]
>>> res = {}
>>> for tup in data:
...     res[tup[0]] = res.setdefault(tup[0], 0) + tup[1]
... 
>>> res
{'a': 5, 'c': 9, 'b': 4, 'd': 3}
```

One-liner version without using any imports like itertools,collections etc.

```
 {tup[0]: SELF_REFERENCE.setdefault(tup[0], 0) + tup[1]  for tup in data}
```

Is it possible in Python to use a reference to the object currently being comprehended?

If not, is there any way to achieve this in a one-liner without using any imports i.e. using basic list/dict comprehension and inbuilt functions?

Comment: `SELF_REFERENCE` is under construction, in the comprehension :)

Comment: You can do something like `sum((Counter(dict([x])) for x in data), Counter())` instead...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is not. A dict comprehension produces a *new* item for each iteration, and your code needs to produce *fewer* items (consolidating values).

There is no way to access keys produced in an earlier iteration, not without using (ugly, unpythonic) side-effect tricks. The `dict` object that is going to be produced by the comprehension doesn't exist yet, so there is no way to produce a self-reference either.

Just stick to your `for` loop, it is far more readable.

The alternative would be to use sorting and grouping, a O(NlogN) algorithm vs. the simple O(N) of your straight loop:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = {key: sum(t[1] for t in group) 
       for key, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
```

Comment: *"The dict object that is going to be produced by the comprehension doesn't exist yet"* - Was that really true back then? It isn't now. If it was true, where did the comprehension put the data if not into a dict object?

Comment: @KellyBundy I suppose what was meant is that the dictionary under construction isn't available in `locals()` or otherwise user-accessible (as opposed to existence).

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I suspect it *is* even user-accessible. At least the list of a list comp is, I've done that a few times, it can be found in `gc.get_objects()`.`Not sure I've done it with dict.

Comment: @KellyBundy I got your `gc.get_objects` suggestion [working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76997570/365102) with list comprehensions, but not with dict comprehensions.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq [Working dict comp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77001410/12671057).

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"No, there is not. A dict comprehension produces a new item for each iteration"* - That's not right. It *can* produce fewer items, by filtering with an `if` clause or by overwriting items by using repeated keys (as in the question's attempt).

Comment: @KellyBundy I am fully aware of those details but they make no difference to the answer. No point in complicating matters here with too much irrelevant detail.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a oneliner. Instead use `collections.defaultdict` and a simple for loop:

```
>>> pairs = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 4), ('c', 9), ('b', 1), ('d', 3)]
>>> result = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key, value in pairs:
...     result[key] += value
...
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 5, 'c': 9, 'b': 4, 'd': 3})
```

It is easy to understand, pythonic and fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> reduce(add, (Counter(dict([x])) for x in data))
Counter({'c': 9, 'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'd': 3})
```

Comment: NOTE: In Python 3 the reduce method has been moved into the functools package.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost like, what you are trying to do. But I won't recommend this, as the readability suffers.

```
data = [('a',1),('b',3),('a',4),('c',9),('b',1),('d',3)]
print reduce(lambda d,i: [d.__setitem__(i[0],d.get(i[0],0)+i[1]),d][1], data, {})
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 5, 'c': 9, 'b': 4, 'd': 3}
```

Comment: This solution hurts my eyes :-)

Comment: @Abhijit Me says sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Super-awful hack for **dict** comprehension, finding the dict being built by the comprehension and making it available as `self` during the comprehension. I have three phases:

1. **Mark** the dict by putting a special item into it, with a special marker object as key and an empty list as value. That appears to make the dict register itself for cyclic garbage collection (since the list could lead to a reference cycle).
2. **Find** the dict in `gc.objects()` (objects registered for cyclic garbage collection), identifying it by looking for the marker. Then remove the special item.
3. **Fill** the dict with the data we *actually* want, using `self` to reference the dict.

```py
import gc

data = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 4), ('c', 9), ('b', 1), ('d', 3)]

res = {
    (marker if phase == 'mark' else tup[0]):
        ([] if phase == 'mark' else self.get(tup[0], 0) + tup[1])
    for marker in [object()]
    for phase in ['mark', 'find', 'fill']
    for self in [
        None if phase == 'mark' else
        next(
            o for o in gc.get_objects()
            if type(o) is dict
            and next(iter(o), None) is marker
            and not o.clear()
        ) if phase == 'find' else
        self
    ]
    if phase != 'find'
    for tup in ([None] if phase == 'mark' else data)
}

print(res)
```

Output as desired ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZJBTsMwEEUllj7FsLItQtUKFoCUK3CBKEJu4qSG1I6cqUSFOAmbbuBQnAZ7TAJRFW8y43n-_uPMx1d_xJ2zp9PnAZvru-8LNPveeYS2YqxWqCCHQnDFM9jIDATfhuiGorh3S1EVovupmriauJIxr4eg8cYgLLFX_kV7MA30OzVoyHPgcY-D7kKKh75Yl_KBYDpQlIvwoLtm1WoU6VQGawlXJLEpJSk0zsN4o4XCbZ91hSKYGotJN9aScAa8MbZO367jf2S8jMDJ2qOzesnbBFn9imLK4nIk56JWW0X7T8nWIOSMC8p47LVwEswAtalwVla2TuIGtQ9QRn6ITR2f0w7BrapOK__vKjlvgbqftxA7pyQ9xoRfjvj0RuHpY1uiiFaW_1ucKsneGeu9sSjCfMg0fL8zOM7iDw)):

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 9, 'd': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Obviously, this should not be used for any practical purpose.

Based on [@superb rain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65228120/365102), by filtering through `gc.get_objects`, we can get the list comprehension under construction:

```
import gc

def get_first_obj(obj_ids):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) in obj_ids or obj is obj_ids:
            continue
        return obj

obj_ids = set(id(obj) for obj in gc.get_objects())
xs = [(get_first_obj(obj_ids).append("Evil!"), i)[1] for i in range(5)]
print(xs)
```

Output:

```
['Evil!', 0, 'Evil!', 1, 'Evil!', 2, 'Evil!', 3, 'Evil!', 4]
```

Note that this is not very robust; for instance what would happen when `get_first_obj` is not called immediately?

---

Here, we print out new objects created during the comprehension as follows:

```
import gc

def print_objs(obj_ids):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) in obj_ids or obj is obj_ids:
            continue
        print(id(obj), obj)

obj_ids = set(id(obj) for obj in gc.get_objects())
xs = [(print_objs(obj_ids), i)[1] for i in range(5)]
```

Output:

```
139842827736960 []
139842827736960 [0]
139842827879264 ('sep', 'end', 'file', 'flush')
139842827736960 [0, 1]
139842827879264 ('sep', 'end', 'file', 'flush')
139842828122560 []
139842832825536 {'Py_Repr': [{...}, [...]]}
139842827736960 [0, 1, 2]
139842827879264 ('sep', 'end', 'file', 'flush')
139842828122560 []
139842832825536 {'Py_Repr': [{...}, [...]]}
139842827736960 [0, 1, 2, 3]
139842827879264 ('sep', 'end', 'file', 'flush')
139842828122560 []
139842832825536 {'Py_Repr': [{...}, [...]]}
```

It looks like the first item printed is usually the comprehension-produced object.

Interestingly, nothing is printed during a dict comprehension.