# Python: Referring to a list comprehension in the list comprehension itself?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This thought just came to my mind. Say for whatever reason you wanted to get the unique elements of a list via a list comprehension in Python.

`[i if i in {created_comprehension} else 0 for i in [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`

`[1, 2, 0, 0, 3]`

I dunno, I don't really have a purpose for this but it'd be cool if it was possible to refer to the comprehension as it's being created.

(e.g. [How to remove duplicate items from a list using list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549345/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-list-comprehension) is a similar question)

Comment: Unless there is some magic I am not aware of, you're better off using a for loop and updating another list in there.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume `i in {created_comprehension}` was meant to be `i not in {created_comprehension}`. At least that's what the data suggests.

So here's a fun horrible abuse that I wouldn't trust to always work. Mainly to demonstrate that the argument *"it's impossible because it's not yet assigned"* is wrong. While the list object indeed isn't assigned yet, it *does* already *exist* while it's being built.

```
>>> import gc
>>> [i if i not in self else 0
     for ids in [set(map(id, gc.get_objects()))]
     for self in [next(o for o in gc.get_objects() if o == [] and id(o) not in ids)]
     for i in [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
```

This gets the ids of all objects tracked for garbage collection *before* the new list gets created, and then *after* it got created, we find it by searching for a newly tracked empty list. Call it `self` and then you can use it. So the middle two lines are a general recipe. I also successfully used it for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65227647/13008439), but it got closed before I could post.

A nicer version:

```
>>> [i if i not in self else 0
     for old in [ids()] for self in [find(old)]
     for i in [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
```

That used these helper functions:

```
def ids():
    import gc
    return set(map(id, gc.get_objects()))

def find(old):
    import gc
    return next(o for o in gc.get_objects() if o == [] and id(o) not in old)
```

Comment: Wow. This is... horrifying. In an amusing way, but still, horrifying. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Added a nicer version now. I'd say it's almost ready for putting it on PyPI.

Comment: Hah. (Silly) Suggestion: Incorporate `gc.disable()` at the beginning of `ids` followed by `gc.enable()` at the end of `find` so you prevent generation changes in between and can look solely at the youngest generation (calling `gc.get_objects(0)`) to reduce the number of objects examined. Clearly performance is the most important thing in this insanity. :-) (Not sure this is guaranteed to work; should check if a `gc` might occur between `BUILD_LIST` and `ids()` call; might help to wrap `ids()` as `(ids(),)` to avoid making a `list`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah that sounds great, given how the youngest generation is usually rather small. I also thought about optimizing space by only storing the ids of empty lists. I'm using 3.9, thought `in [ids()]` already doesn't build a list but [directly assigns](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations). Turns out it's neither, it's `BUILD_TUPLE` instead (and the iteration over it). Odd. For `[find(old)]` it's `STORE_FAST` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is purely speculation on my part, and I don't have data to back it up

I don't think you can refer to a list comprehension as it is being built. Python will first have to create the list, allocate memory or it, and add elements to it, before it binds it to a variable name. Therefore, I think you'll end up with a `NameError` if you try to refer to the list, while it's being built in a list-comp

You might ultimately, therefore, want a `set` to hold your uniques, and build your list from there (Oh God! this is hacky):

```
In [11]: L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

In [12]: s = set(L)

In [13]: answer = [sub[0] for sub in [(i,s.remove(i)) if i in s else (0,0) for i in L]]

In [14]: answer
Out[14]: [1, 2, 0, 0, 3]

In [15]: s
Out[15]: set()
```

Comment: Until CPython 2.6 it was possible to access the list using `locals()['_[1]']`: `[x if x not in locals()['_[1]'] else 0 for x in L]`. For this I find the good ol' *seen set* hack much easier to understand: `seen = set(); [x if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else 0 for x in L]`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is just an experiment. I compare a `list comprehension` and a `list` inside a `list comprehension`.

I want `x` to contain elements from `[1,2,1,2,3,4,5]` only if those elements are in this `list comprehension` `[e for e in range(3,6)]` which should be `[3,4,5]`

```
x = [i for a in [e for e in range(3,6)] for i in [1,2,1,2,3,4,5] if i == a]
```

The output is right:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```