# Where do I put the if statement in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've just started learning python few weeks ago. I'm trying to convert this for loop to a list comprehension. The goal is to retrieve all values with USA as a key. Here's my code:

```
countries = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':{'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}
gold_medals = []
for i in countries:
    for j in i:
        if countries[i]['USA'] not in gold_medals:
                gold_medals.append(countries[i]['USA'])
```

I tried converting it to list comprehension:

```
gold_medals2 = [countries[i]['USA'] for i in countries for j in i]
```

I was able to retrieve all the values associated to 'USA' but there are repetitions. I assume it's because I have no if statement to filter the result.

Comment: @Chris: That one doesn't work here sadly; they're using their `if` for deduping, and an `if` in a listcomp won't be able to do that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, good catch. I voted too quickly based on the title of the question and didn't look closely enough at the (at the time) unformatted code. Retracted and deleted.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well darn... I wrote and was just about to post an answer doing it with a list comp accessing itself while being built :-(. Not nice to close the question after yourself.

Comment: @superbrain: Well, I found an even better duplicate that I've now linked as the primary; you can always post it there. I'm horrified/intrigued at what evil you're contemplating to access a listcomp in the process of being built though. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Found a question that's directly about referencing the list, [answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65228120/13008439).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're trying to do with an `if` in a listcomp; listcomps don't bind to the name they're assigned to until they're finished, so there *is* no `gold_medals2` to perform membership testing against.

You can use other tricks for deduping (while preserving order) though, e.g.:

```
gold_medals2 = list(dict.fromkeys(countries[i]['USA'] for i in countries for j in i))
```

On modern Python (3.6+) with insertion-ordered `dict`s, for hashable values, `dict.fromkeys` quickly produces the unique items from the input in the order each was first observed. `list` strips off the (garbage) values (all `None`) and hash table structure so you end up with the unique items with no kruft. If you're on an older Python, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

Bonus, it's much faster than what you were doing. Your original solution is a `O(n²)` solution; using `dict.fromkeys` keeps it at `O(n)` (so if you multiply the input size by 10x, you'll only do ~10x more work, not 100x more work).

Comment: I somehow managed to do it with list comprehension but probably much worse in terms of time and hard to read: ```goldmedals = [goldmedals:=[] if i is None else [goldmedals.append(countries[j]['USA']) for j in i if countries[j]['USA'] not in goldmedals] for i in (None, countries)][0]```. (Not really an expert on assignment expression).

Comment: @HenryTjhia: Why? WHY WOULD YOU DO THIS?!?!? I'll note, the `[0]` indexing at the end and assignment of `goldmedals = ` isn't necessary, since the walrus did the assignment to `goldmedals` already (for reasons I somewhat disagree with, the walrus assignment applies outside the scope of the comprehension). I think `[goldmedals:=[] if i is None else [goldmedals.append(countries[j]['USA']) for j in i if countries[j]['USA'] not in goldmedals] for i in (None, countries)]` would have the same effect. Obviously a ludicrous solution though. :-)

Comment: Without the indexing at the end, the expression will give output such as ```[[36, 46, 35], [None, None, None]]```, while ```goldmedals``` will print out as ```[None, None, None]```. Tested on Python 3.9.

Comment: @HenryTjhia: Ah, I missed the precedence issue. You'd need to parenthesize the walrus to avoid reassigning it on the second outer loop: `[(goldmedals:=[]) if i is None else [goldmedals.append(countries[j]['USA']) for j in i if countries[j]['USA'] not in goldmedals] for i in (None, countries)]`. The result of the expression is ignored (`goldmedals` will have the correct value in it already). I'd feel bad about it, but this was already violating "no side-effects in functional constructs" in half a dozen ways, so whatever.